# How do I handle uppercase and lowercase characters in a custom url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, case-insensitive

I want to let users have links to their profiles using their registered usernames.

I store their username exactly how they give it.

I set up my routes to match /:name and then used find_by_name to get it. The problem I have is when you type in example.com/username it doesn't work the name: Username. (Note the uppercase/lowercase difference)

So my question is how can I ignore case in urls?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do this? So if I register as BobKaufman, it won't recognize me if I enter "bobkaufman"? Bear in mind that case-sensitivity on passwords is an entirely different matter.

Comment: No, that IS what I want. I want it to recognize any version of "bobkaufman". So it could be "BobKaufman", "BOBKaufman", "BobKaufmAn" etc..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'd always toLower() usernames before reading/writing URL's.

Comment: Ruby's version of toLower() is downcase. When do I downcase the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the `username` downcased along with a `display_name` which is in the format they gave it to you. Then, downcase any input and match it with `username` and only use `display_name` for, well, display :)

If you wanted, you could even redirect to `/DisPlAyName` from `/username` after you look up the record.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to convert the username in the database and in rails to lower (or upper) case when you are doing the comparison.

```
User.where('lower(username) = ?', params[:name].downcase).first
```

Or if you are still using rails 2:

```
User.find(:first, :conditions => ['lower(username) = ?', params[:name].downcase])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store a lowercase version of their username. When they type in

`example.com/UsErNaMe` or `example.com/Username`

downcase it and match it to the lowercase version in the database.

---OR---

Just make the user have a lowercase username everywhere. (Downcase it when its made)

---OR---

Have a constant type of username. So always have the first letter capitalized or something. Store it as lower case and upcase the first letter everytime you show it.