# How do I save a lowercase version of username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How can I save a lowercase version of a username? I'm trying to do what was said in "[How do I handle uppercase and lowercase characters in a custom url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220865/how-do-i-handle-uppercase-and-lowercase-characters-in-a-custom-url)".

I want to save both a lowercase and a case-sensitive version of usernames in two different columns.

Thank you.

Comment: [String#downcase](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-downcase)

Comment: If you're trying to do the same as in that question, did you try using the answer to that question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle uppercase and lowercase characters in a custom url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220865/how-do-i-handle-uppercase-and-lowercase-characters-in-a-custom-url)

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Sorry, i didn't know that I could have answered to that question. I thought that would have been an answer containing a question which is pretty wired. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something like this in your model where `lower_username` is the other username column in your table.

```
#Simply populates the field on the database

before_save :downcase_username
```

or

```
#If you have validation of the username (ie must be a unique field),
#you may want to assign the lowercase username before the validation occurs.

before_validation :downcase_username
```

Create the private method to populate the lowercase username column

```
private

def downcase_username
  self.lower_username = self.username.downcase
end
```

Comment: On create `downcase_username` would be called twice. You only need `before_save` what is trigger on create and update.

Answer (score 1):

```
# in user model
before_validation :generate_lowercase_username

private
  def generate_lowercase_username
    self.lowercase_username = username.downcase
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.username = "AbCd"
@user.lowercase_username = @user.username.downcase
@user.save
```